# having issues with database on live server with codeigniter project

Tags: database, codeigniter

I am working on a project using codeigniter. I completed the login and registration coding and works fine on my local computer. But when I upload the files to live server then it gives me following error

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to select the specified database: zafarsal_membership

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

In database.php I have added correct information. And zafarsal_membership database does exist there but still it gives me this error. Could you please help me where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the usual suspects:

- Does the database user have read/write access to the database?
- Did you select the right database driver?
- Does your connection to the database succeed?
- Are you running the same version of the database server locally and on your server?

In 90% of the cases, it's one of the above.

Comment: Above two points are already fine because I recently uploaded a new project to this server with same detail and it is working. How to find out whether database connect is succeeded or not? and also how would I find the version of both databases?

Comment: The error message clearly shows that it fails while **selecting** the database. You wouldn't get to this point if you were unable to connect. Check if your DB user has access to the 'zafarsal_membership' database and that there isn't any typo in the DB name.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error... just change the $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
to $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
[Here are the diferences between "mysql" and "mysqli":](http://rudiv.se/Article/tutorials/when-to-use-mysql-vs-mysqli-vs-pdo-in-php)
Hope it helps you!