# Codeigniter check query on empty result issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project with this controller that must check login and password.

```
class Account extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $login=$this->input->post('login');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->query("call utlCheckUser('{$login}','{$password}');");
        if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            echo $query->num_rows();
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Mistake';
        }
    }

}
```

Stored procedure utlCheckUser returns result of select query like this:

```
SELECT user FROM utl_users where user=$in_user and password=$in_password;
```

If I try it first time it shows right result (num_rows if I enter right data and mistake if there is wrong data).
If I refresh page it shows error

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to select the specified database: service

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

if I refresh page again sometimes error shows sometimes result and I can't find out why. Any suggestions? 
config/database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '***';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '***';
$db['default']['database'] = 'service';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

**UPDATE**
$this->load->database('service'); this doesn't works. Says You have specified an invalid database connection group.

Comment: try to pass db name in $this->load->database(); else setup your db in config/database.php

Comment: Added my database.php

Comment: As @RakeshSharma said use $this->load->database(); or autoload database in config/autoload.php

Comment: autoload database library $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); in config/autoload.php

Comment: There is  $this->load->database(); right before query

Comment: Is your DB exists with the name `service`, re check once.

Comment: Yes, It sure exists. I used it in my previous project without codeigniter.

Comment: Found the solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465570/having-issues-with-database-on-live-server-with-codeigniter-project